# What happens if I purchase a bundle containing a character that I already own?

Tags: crash-team-racing-nitro-fueled

While the Grand Prix event is active, in the Pit Stop shop we can buy a sort of bundle containing a new character, a skin and a kart paint. But characters can be purchased also alone, costing a lot lower.

If I already own a character and his/her bundle comes out will it be cheaper or at the original price? I'm wondering if I can purchase the single character no matter what or if it's always better to wait and buy the bundle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bundle is discounted.
Ami bundle (with character, paint, 11 and her competition skin) costs 5175.

But since I already own standard Ami now the price is reduced to 3825, the amount missing is what I previously paid for Ami, 1350 coins (= 1500 - 10%)